# Constant Distribution

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics

As far as I know, Mathematica lacks a definition for a probability distribution representing a constant random variable.

Is this assertion correct?

Is there a problem in making such a distribution well-defined in Mathematica (assuming we treat it as a continuous rather than a discrete distribution)?

In principle, we could add definitions for this distribution, e.g.

```
CDF[ConstantDistribution[μ_]] ^:= UnitStep[# - μ] &
```

How would I find what definitions are needed to make it a "first class" member of the set of distributions supported by Mathematica?  So that, for example, it could be used in functions such as `TransformedDistribution`?

In general, there are ways to work around the lack of such a distribution, but just as it is sometimes useful to have a function such as `Identity` (e.g. to pass to a function that transforms an input) it can be useful to have the "trivial" distribution.

Comment: Is this too limited: `constantD = UniformDistribution[{4.3, 4.3}]; RandomVariate[constantD, 10]` ?  This results in `{4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3}`.  But the `PDF` and `CDF` functions don't work with this.

Comment: @JimB I think defining it in terms of pre-defined distributions would be a simple way forward.  But as you show, your example doesn't work fully and neither does setting the `SD = 0` in a Normal distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A relatively simple trick can achieve this

```
ConstantDistribution[m_] = TransformedDistribution[m, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}];
```

This behaves as desired for some key functions

```
{Mean, Variance, CDF[#, t] &, CharacteristicFunction[#, t] &}[ConstantDistribution[m]] // Through // InputForm
(* {m, 0, Piecewise[{{1, m - t <= 0}}, 0], E^(I*m*t)} *)
```

Comment: Wow!  Even `Expectation` works with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

In[35]:= dist = ProbabilityDistribution[1, {x, a, a, 1}];

In[36]:= DistributionParameterQ[dist]

Out[36]= True

In[39]:= {Mean[dist], Variance[dist], CDF[dist, x], 
  Expectation[s^2 + 1, s [Distributed] dist]} // InputForm

Out[39]//InputForm=
{a, 0, Piecewise[{{1, a <= x}}, 0], 1 + a^2}

Comment: Interesting - technically you have defined a discrete distribution that only takes the value `a`, whereas my answer defined a continuous distribution.
Mathematica makes a distinction between the two types, at least in `PDF`

Comment: The integral of a finite function from a to a is zero... This really should not work, but I guess the framework is just too robust ;)

In[62]:= td = TransformedDistribution[3, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}];

In[63]:= DistributionDomain[td]

Out[63]= Interval[{3, 3}]

In[64]:= DistributionParameterQ[td]

Out[64]= True

In[69]:= PDF[td, x] // InputForm

Out[69]//InputForm=
Piecewise[{{0, x != 3}}, Indeterminate]

Answer (score 1):

```
EmpiricalDistribution[{1} -> {m}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution:

```
ConstantDistribution[m_Real] := UniformDistribution[{m, m}]
```

or

```
ConstantDistribution[m_Integer] := DiscreteUniformDistribution[{m, m}]
```

For some reason `Expectation` works only with the discrete variant. Sampling works with both.